# OpenCV Tesseract

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I tried to run this code https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/samples/end_to_end_recognition.cpp

as project in c++(VS12) but I get this

```
TIME_REGION_DETECTION = 21744.2
TIME_GROUPING = 1187.99
OCRTesseract(33): Tesseract not found.
TIME_OCR_INITIALIZATION = 2.85173
OCRTesseract(00): Tesseract not found.
OCR output = "" lenght = 0
OCRTesseract(00): Tesseract not found.
OCR output = "" lenght = 0
OCRTesseract(00): Tesseract not found.
OCR output = "" lenght = 0
OCRTesseract(00): Tesseract not found.
OCR output = "" lenght = 0
OCRTesseract(00): Tesseract not found.
OCR output = "" lenght = 0
TIME_OCR = 42.6972
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you install tessaract after building OpenCV, you should be sure that OpenCV find Tessaract when trying to generate the project files using CMake.

### 1- Install first Tessaract:

This link may be helpful: http://emop.tamu.edu/Installing-Tesseract-Windows8

### 2- When trying to generate the visual studio using CMake, you should be sure that CMake find Tessaract:

In fact, if it didn't find it the flag `HAVE_TESSERACT` will not be defined, and as a result the library opencv_text300.dll will generate this message `OCRTesseract(33): Tesseract not found.` always you try to access to Tessarct engine. You can see the behaviour here:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/text/src/ocr_tesseract.cpp#L142

### 3- Generate the correct opencv_text300.dll built with `HAVE_TESSERACT`.

### 4- Execute your executable so that the program run correctly.